# AttributeError: 'CLIPVisionModelWithProjection' object has no attribute 'get_image_features'

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, stable-diffusion

I am working on a stable diffusion model while implementing a simple code example given below in the link. I have followed the same steps mentioned in the link, but still it gives an error

```
https://replicate.com/lambdal/stable-diffusion-image-variation
```

**Code**

```
from pathlib import Path
from lambda_diffusers import StableDiffusionImageEmbedPipeline

from PIL import Image
import torch

#device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
device = "cpu"
pipe = StableDiffusionImageEmbedPipeline.from_pretrained("lambdalabs/sd-image-variations-diffusers")
pipe = pipe.to(device)

im = Image.open("/home/cvpr/Desktop/bird.jpg")
num_samples = 4
image = pipe(num_samples*[im], guidance_scale=3.0)
image = image["sample"]

base_path = Path("outputs/im2im")
base_path.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
for idx, im in enumerate(image):
    im.save(base_path/f"{idx:06}.jpg")
```

**Trackback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_1/lambda-diffusers/image_variation.py", line 46, in <module>
    image = pipe(num_samples*[im], guidance_scale=3.0)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_1/lambda-diffusers/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_1/lambda-diffusers/lambda_diffusers/pipelines/pipeline_stable_diffusion_im_embed.py", line 77, in __call__
    image_embeddings = self.image_encoder.get_image_features(**input_image)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_1/lambda-diffusers/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1614, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
AttributeError: 'CLIPVisionModelWithProjection' object has no attribute 'get_image_features'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a version conflict problem you have to modify the `pipe` part

**From:**

```
pipe = StableDiffusionImageEmbedPipeline.from_pretrained("lambdalabs/sd-image-variations-diffusers")
```

**To:**

```
pipe = StableDiffusionImageEmbedPipeline.from_pretrained("lambdalabs/sd-image-variations-diffusers", revision="273115e88df42350019ef4d628265b8c29ef4af5")
```